# Parsing JSON & work with ObjectMapper,SwiftRealm,ObjectMapperAdditions,ObjectMapperAdditionsRealm & Alamofire

Tags: json, swift, cocoapods, alamofire, objectmapper

regards, I am trying to serialize a json from the placeHolder page, the users one (https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/ users), I am trying to use the following libraries together:

-> Alamofire

-> RealmSwift

-> ObjectMapper

-> ObjectMapperAdditions

-> ObjectMapper_Realm

Here is the model that I am defining, but the problem is that SwiftRealm does not support the ArrayDictionary data type, as you try changing the type in the COMPANY & ADDRESS attributes, which are of the array type, try to put it as List  , [Address1]?, Address1, List , etc. but it does not work, it always marks the same error "The operation could not be completed, ObjectMapper could not serialize the response.", so it can be received as an object but it can not be saved in RealmSwift or failing that What to do, but you will also receive as JSON or ARRAY and it is also not possible to serialize it, have you implemented something like that?

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift
import ObjectMapper
import ObjectMapperAdditions
import ObjectMapper_Realm

class PlaceHolderClass: Object, Mappable {

    @objc dynamic var id = 0
    @objc dynamic var name = ""
    @objc dynamic var username = ""
    @objc dynamic var email = ""
    var address: Address1?
    @objc dynamic var phone = ""
    @objc dynamic var website = ""
    var company: Company?

    required convenience init?(map: Map) {
        self.init()
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {

        id <- map["id"]
        name <- map["name"]
        username <- map["username"]
        email <-   map["email"]
        address <- map["address"]
        phone <- map["phone"]
        website <- map["website"]
        company <- map["company"]

    }  
}

class Address1: Object, Mappable {

     var street = List<String>()
     var suite = List<String>()
     var city = List<String>()
     var zipcode = List<String>()

    var geo: Geo?

    required convenience init?(map: Map) {
        self.init()
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {

        street <- map["street"]
        suite <- map["suite"]
        city <- map["city"]
        zipcode <- map["zipcode"]
        geo <- map["geo"]

    }

}
class Geo: Object, Mappable {

     var lat  = List<String>()
     var lng  = List<String>()

    required convenience init?(map: Map) {
        self.init()
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        lat <- map["lat"]
        lng <- map["lng"]
    }

}
class Company: Object, Mappable {

     var name  = List<String>()
     var catchPhrase  = List<String>()
     var bs  = List<String>()

    required convenience init?(map: Map) {
        self.init()
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {

        name <- map["name"]
        catchPhrase <- map["catchPhrase"]
        bs <- map["bs"]

    }
}
```

My request Code:

```
func requestPlaceHolder(){

    let URL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"

    Alamofire.request(URL).responseObject{ (response: DataResponse<PlaceHolderClass>) in

        switch response.result {

        case .success(let objects):

            let realm = try! Realm()

            let myPlaceHolderResponse = PlaceHolderClass(value: response.result.value)


            try! realm.write {
                realm.add(myPlaceHolderResponse, update: true)
                print("se agrego correctamente")
            }

            print(Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL)


        case .failure(let error):
              print("Ocurrio el siguiente error \(error.localizedDescription)")

        }
            print(Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL)
}
}
```